# Incorrect username and password error for Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I'm pressing Paypal login button I'm getting the error that incorrect username and password. I have set thing correct. I'm logging with the same id which I have logged in to generate my client id.I have tried everything.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Regular login on paypal, adaptive payment, subscription or in other words what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: i'm working on demo just doing paypal integration. i'm doing login with regular button. but i'm getting alert of incorrect username and password in android app.

Comment: So you are using sandbox I take it. If so, you need to go to sandbox.paypal.com and make a separate registration there. Sandbox paypal and production paypal are not interchangeable.

Comment: Please check your entries and try again. i'm getting this error when i'm loging in sandbox.paypal.com

Comment: thanks@AlexHristov i have resolved my error .:)

Answer (score 0):

You Are trying Login with your PayPal Account but you need to login with your Sandbox Test Account Username and password which is in https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

Please Refer this Tutorial How To PayPal Sandbox https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sandbox/